# how can I view tar archiving process in Terminal using this applescript?

Tags: tar

I got this script working as an app in Finder but I would like to get an alert when the archive is done. Any idea how I can do this?

```
    tell application "Finder"
set theItems to selection
repeat with _a from 1 to (count of theItems)
    set theItem to (item _a of theItems) as alias
    set itemPath to quoted form of POSIX path of theItem
    set fileName to name of theItem
    set theFolder to POSIX path of (container of theItem as alias)
    set zipFile to quoted form of (theFolder & fileName & ".tgz")
    do shell script "tar czvf " & zipFile & " " & itemPath
end repeat
```

end tell

many thanks
Erik